# How to remove apostrophes from a list in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, replace

I need to remove apostrophes -> ' <- from a list, within python, without using any add-ons, so only built in functions.

E.g. I need a list like:

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

into

```
lista = [ a, b, c, d]
```

I've tried using for with .replace or making the list into a string then replacing, but I haven't had anything work yet.

Any chance you could help?

Comment: you have list with strings

Comment: Here's code to remove all apostrophes from that list:

Comment: You seem to misunderstand notation. In your list apostrophes indicate strings/characters and they are not part of them. You can easily check it: ```for x in lista:\n\t print x``` ( '\n' means new line, '\t' means tabulator)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to concatenate strings with a specified separator.

For example:

```
>>> strings = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> print(', '.join(strings))
A, B, C
```

Furthermore, in your case, [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) may also help:

```
>>> strings = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> print('strings = [{}]'.format(', '.join(strings)))
strings = [A, B, C]
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot remove apostrophes from a list because that's pretty much how you identify what a list is. However the apostrophes will not interfere with anything you do with the list. The apostrophes show that the elements are strings.